# How do I display a single oject from an array in VueJs?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I am using a for loop to display a list of items on my page. As you can see, each object is declared in my array.

```
const animals = [
  {
    name: "monkey",
    food: "fruit",
    img: "images/fruit.jpg",
  },
  {
    name: "horse",
    food: "hay",
    img: "images/hay.jpg",
  },  
  {
    name: "sealion",
    food: "fish",
    img: "images/fish.jpg",
  }
];

new Vue ({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    zoo: animals
  }
});
```

The below code would print a list of animals and the food they like on a listings page.

```
<ul>
    <li v-for="(item, index) in zoo">
        <p>{{index }} {{ item.name }}</p>
        <p>{{index }} {{ item.food }}</p>
    </li>
</ul>
```

However, I also need to use the information stored in this array elsewhere on my site. But, this time not in a loop.

For a separate details page, I would need the information for only the third animal (index position 2)

```
<h2>My favorite animal is a {{ item[2].name }} and it eats {{ item[2].food }} </h2>
```

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: `My favorite animal is a {{ zoo[2].name }} and it eats {{ zoo[2].food }}`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code will work and it's OK but to be more defensive it's good to create a method (or filter) to get a specific element from the Array, for method example:

```js
methods: {
  getAnimalByIndex({ animals = [], index = 0 }) {
    return animals[index] || {}
  }
}
```

...and then use in template like below:

```
<h2>My favorite animal is a {{ getAnimalByIndex({ animals, index: 2 }).name }} and it eats {{ getAnimalByIndex({ animals, index: 2 }).food }} </h2>
```

Thanks to above you can provide fallback value or be sure that will be OK even if animals is undefined ;)

Moreover, if you want to get always third animal then maybe it's good idea to use computed value, like below:

```
computed: {
  thirdAnimal() {
    return this.animals[2] || {}
  }
}
```

...and use computed value in template:

```
<h2>My favorite animal is a {{ thirdAnimal.name }} and it eats {{ thirdAnimal.food }} </h2>
```

Comment: This works fantastic so thank you very much. Really appreciate your help as now I understand.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a computed property to return a specific object in the array. If the property is reactive, the computed will also be reactive and watch for updates to that property.

You could create a method to find a certain object in array, by index, or whatever you want i suppose:

```js
computed: {
  sealion () {
    return animals[2]
  }
},
methods: {
  getAnimal (i) {
    return animals[i]
  },
  getAnimal (name) {
    animals.forEach((animal) => {
      if (animal.name === name) return animal
    }
  }
}
```